# hiding specific input fields in apex repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

So currently i'm using

`<apex:repeat>`

to populate a section for input fields, but there are specific fields that I want to have visible, but not editable. I understand how to do it with a single field, but how would I approach this for repeat?

Say if I had a condition of `field name = 'test__c'`  make it an output field instead of input field in that repeat?

Comment: have you looked at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21419/conditional-rendering-of-apex-repeat-element   or maybe https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137972/repeat-rendered-for-certain-condition

Comment: in any case, you should provide any coding attempts you have made so far as pointed out in [ask] so others can better assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rendered` attribute in `<apex:repeat>` to render your fields as input or output as desired.

Here's an example:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!list}" var="{!listVar}">
    <apex:outputField value="{!listVar}" rendered="{!IF(listVar.Name == 'test'), true, false}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!listVar}" rendered="{!IF(listVar.Name == 'test'), false, true}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know exactly what field you are going to show in

```
<apex:outputField>
```

you can use output Field : -

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstvalue}" var="item">
    <apex:outputText value="{!item.Abc__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!item.def__c}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

I am showing Abc__c in outputfield where as def__c is being shown in  inputfield.

Comment: use inputField instead on inputText in your example